# Ionic - one signal push notifications sent twice

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, onesignal

I am sending push notifications with One Signal to all users from the backend that uses Laravel like this:

```
OneSignal::sendNotificationToAll($notification->message);
```

I have set it up on the frontend side like this:

```
angular.module('coop.services')
.service('PushService', function(
  AppSettings,
  $rootScope,
  $q
) {
  var service = {
    init: function() {
      if (!window.plugins || !window.plugins.OneSignal) {
        return;
      }

      window.plugins.OneSignal
      .startInit( AppSettings.oneSignalAppId)
      .endInit();
    },

    receivePush: function(data) {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('push:received', data);
    },

    getDeviceId: function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      if (window.plugins) {
        window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds(function(ids) {
          deferred.resolve(ids.userId);
        });
      }
      else {
        deferred.reject();
      }

      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };

  return service;
});
```

I have tested both from the backend and from the One signal dashboard and when I am sending notification I get two notifications for each I send. One with alarm icon and one without any, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you might have enabled mozila and Chrome with wrong settings, had similar problem I couldn't disactivate the browser though, I just made a new onesignal app and solved.